# ITextSharp: Text not wrapping around image within cell

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I am having real problems, I have a cell with a phrase, and I want a small icon to the left of the phrase, but each element is being rendered on a new line

here is my code that returns the cell:

```
var cell = new PdfPCell();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(21, 21);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

g.Clear(Color.White);

SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colour);
g.FillEllipse(brush, 0, 0, 20, 20);
brush.Dispose();

g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0);

g.Dispose();

var imgIcon = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bitmap.Dispose();
//imgIcon.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.TEXTWRAP | iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
cell.AddElement(imgIcon);

var phrase = new Phrase(o.ToString(), Report.Fonts.Table);
cell.AddElement(phrase);

//this code scales the image so that it does not fit the cell
foreach (IElement element in cell.CompositeElements)
{
     PdfPTable tblImg = element as PdfPTable;
     if (tblImg != null)
     {
         tblImg.TotalWidth = 10;
         tblImg.LockedWidth = true;
     }
}
return cell;
```

here is the output:

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated

--edit:
here is the output with imgIcon's alignment property set

[image]

Comment: adding any alignment to the image just centers the image on it's own line, I am very confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iTextSharp `Image` object is displayed as a *block* element (in CSS terms). You need to explicitly wrap the `Image` in a `Chunk` to get *inline* display, something like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1) {
  TotalWidth = 100, LockedWidth = true, 
  HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
};
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
Phrase p = new Phrase(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
p.Add(new Phrase("Print"));
cell.AddElement(p);
table.AddCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell();
p = new Phrase(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
p.Add(new Phrase("A long phrase that will make the PdfPCell wrap it's containing text."));
cell.AddElement(p);
table.AddCell(cell);
document.Add(table);
```

Code snippet result:

[image: Code snippet result]

Answer (score 0):

I think that this answer:

[Image alignment in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451045/itextsharp-image-alignment-in-text)

May have the answer.  You need to set the alignment of the image:

```
....
imgIcon.Alignment = 6;
cell.AddElement(imgIcon);
....
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, I did see that question before I asked mine, but all that seems to do is just center the image on it's own line

Comment: Yeah, I have tried using paragraphs with no luck, makes no difference