# How to add text followed follow by an image in a PdfPCell?

Tags: .net, image, itext, paragraph

I've created a table and I need to add a small image near the text, in the right. How can I do this?

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("text", font));
Image img = Image.GetInstance("path");
img.ScaleAbsolute(width, height);
cell.AddElement(img);
```

Comment: Here Image belongs to System.Drawing or iText?

Comment: It works fine for me. What's the problem, you are facing?

Comment: Image belongs to iText. The image is added just after text (as a new line), not near the text in the right.

Comment: Split the cell and add text in 1st part and image in 2nd part, hide the common border.

Comment: [Wrap the `Image` object in a `Chunk`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720064/itextsharp-text-not-wrapping-around-image-within-cell/10750635#10750635)