# Balancing text and images across multiple columns in pdf (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, text-alignment

I need to create a PDF file in C#. This PDF file is much like a newspaper with narrow columns of text and images embedded in between them. I know I can create the PDF file with third-party libraries like iTextSharp. I just don't know how to balance the texts and images across multiple columns and pages so that they fit elegantly within each page. Is there any known algorithm for doing this? Is iTextSharp library capable of automatically aligning texts for me? Is there any other library that might be helpful for text and image alignment in PDF file? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe usefull info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451045/itextsharp-image-alignment-in-text . Or you can use "classic" tables in ITextSharp, playing with rowspan / colspan

Comment: This seems to help too: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/89/iTextSharp-Page-Layout-with-Columns

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a library which can automatically align text and images in columns. It's called [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/PdfAutomateLib). It will scale images depending on the scaling mode you set for each image. And allocate text depending on the text overflow action mode you set. It also has inline images which can be used your case, so you can put them in any place in the paragraph.
You can also make the library automatically calculate whether a table fits into the page or not (if you have set column width) and continue the table on the next page or a number of pages if necessary. For this, enable the automatic multi-page spread mode using the method SetAutomaticMultipageSpreadMode.

Here are C# source code examples of real PDF business documents generated with this lib: [Examples](https://go.pdfflow.io/PdfAutomateExamples).
Hope, this will help.

Comment: Are you somehow associated with the pdfflow providers?