# Align image right side using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Code is like

```
iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Logo_Path);
Phrase p = new Phrase("");
logo.RotationDegrees = 180f;
p.Add(new Chunk(logo, 30, 30, false));
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, p, 400f, 5f, 0);
```

but it shows image left alinged..how to make it right alined?

Comment: When you say "it shows image left aligned", what are you looking at? Using `ALIGN_RIGHT` will put the image to the left of the coordinate `400, 5`. One could easily interprete this as left aligned, whereas `ALIGN_RIGHT` means that the right side of the image coincides with `x = 400`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie ..I got what u said..but I'm not getting how to make image right aligned..

Comment: @BrunoLowagie.. I re-read your comment and it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing left and right, and left-aligned and right-aligned.

I have an image of a dog and an image of a fox.

I am addding the dog left-aligned, and the fox right-aligned:

```
Image d = Image.getInstance(DOG);
d.setScaleToFitHeight(false);
Image f = Image.getInstance(FOX);
f.setScaleToFitHeight(false);
Chunk dog = new Chunk(d, 0, 0, false);
Chunk fox = new Chunk(f, 0, 0, false);
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(dog), 250, 750f, 0);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(fox), 250, 750f, 0);
```

This is the result:
[image]

The dog is to the right, because "left-aligned" means that `x = 250` will coincide with the left side of the image will be to the left. The fox is to the left because "right-aligned" means that `x = 250` will coincide with the right side of the image.

Comment: I already did it...your comment helped me (y)..I did `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, p, 530f, 5f, 0);` and its working

Comment: Well, I provided an answer for the sake of completeness in case other people have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"D:\testLogo.png");
            logo.Alignment = 6;
            doc.Add(logo);
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(@"Test"));
            doc.Close();
```

you just need to set Alignment for your image as 6 form Right Alignment

Comment: updated my answer which will work fine, please update this as per your need

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted. The question was about `showTextAligned()` not about `document.add()`. I'll down-vote.

Comment: @Bruno Thanks for your DownVote, the question was to align the Image not showTextAligned(), i had surfed through StackOverflow for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451045/image-alignment-in-text and worked on my local before posting here, thanks for the downvote